# Magento add custom option in the left side filter

Tags: magento, filter

I have products that has custom options like size, color etc. All are unique to the products and not shared by attributes. How can i add these filters on the product listing pages. I hope i write my question clearly. Please let me know if you want more information. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento, two properties will appear as layered navigation filters without you having to do anything:  Price and Categories

Its better to store them as attributes and make them filterable , then it will be displayed in the layered navigation.

You can see [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work/) how layered navigation works.

And if you want to know how to include this layered navigation widget in any of the page, [read this tutorial](http://www.noamdesign.com/blog/magento-include-layered-navigation-in-cms-page-listing-products/)

Comment: I already set up all my 1000+ products using custom options. Also each option like size large, 2x, 3x etc are having different prices so i couldn't set it up using attributes. Please advise. Thanks