# code to filter product by attribute by color in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I need to implement product filter by colour, size list page. I have created one mega menu and want to implement this.

Any idea , how to fix this?

Comment: I do not have clear idea on this. 

I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906791/magento-add-custom-option-in-the-left-side-filter

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Either you can implement using code i.e,

```
$productCollection =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                           ->addAttributeToFilter('color',{{color-option-id}})
                           ->addAttributeToFilter('size',{{size-option-id}});
```

Other filter options can be found in https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

This is through code, if you are talking about layered navigation, then 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work

Please let me know if this works!

Comment: Thanks for your reference, I fixed it