# get the products collection filter by attributes with array of values

Tags: arrays, magento

i want to get the products collection filter by attributes with array of values in magento.

eg:get collection of products whose color from array('red','blue','green') or brand from array('x','y','z').....

note: the attribute filter will not be the intersection .I have mentioned ***`OR`***.So it will be joined to form final products collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look @ [code to filter product by attribute by color in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551687/code-to-filter-product-by-attribute-by-color-in-magento) and [Magento - Wiki - Using Collections in Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)

```
$filter = array(
    'attribute' => 'color',
    'in'        => array('red', 'blue', 'green'), // you may need get the code id of each color
    ),
array(
    'attribute' => 'brand',
    'in'      => array('x','y'),
    ),
));

$productCollection =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                           ->addAttributeToFilter($filter)
```

Comment: my question points to joining filters into a single collection.It must show products either from 1st filter or from 2nd or......

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
 $productCollection =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
 $productCollection ->addFieldToFilter(
                array('color', 'brand'),
                array(
                    array('in' => array('red', 'blue', 'green')),
                    array('in' => rray('x','y'))
                )
            );
```

But color is a select attribute you should pass option's id of red/blue/green values